# dpkg error while installing xorg-dev in chrooted debian

Tags: xorg, dpkg, chroot

I have chrooted debian in android. I am trying to build fluxbox 1.3.7 which needs xorg-dev. so I installed xorg-dev using ::`apt-get instal xorg-dev`
But everytime it shows this error ::

```
root@localhost:/# ls
bin   data  etc   lib         media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr
boot  dev   home  lost+found  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var
root@localhost:/# apt-get install xorg-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
xorg-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
18 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: unrecognized option '--apt'
Try `ischroot --help' for more information.
Setting up x11-common (1:7.7+7) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/x11-common.postinst: 697: /var/lib/dpkg/info/x11-common.postinst: update-rc.d: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package x11-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libice6:arm64:
 libice6:arm64 depends on x11-common; however:
  Package x11-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libice6:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsm6:arm64:
 libsm6:arm64 depends on libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0); however:
  Package libice6:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libsm6:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxt6:arm64:
 libxt6:arm64 depends on libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0); however:
  Package libice6:arm64 is not configured yet.
 libxt6:arm64 depends on libsm6; however:
  Package libsm6:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxt6:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxmu6:arm64:
 libxmu6:arm64 depends on libxt6; however:
  Package libxt6:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxmu6:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxaw7:arm64:
 libxaw7:arm64 depends on libxmu6; however:
  Package libxmu6:arm64 is not configured yet.
 libxaw7:arm64 depends on libxt6; however:
  Package libxt6:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxaw7:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxss1:arm64:
 libxss1:arm64 depends on x11-common; however:
  Package x11-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxss1:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxtst6:arm64:
 libxtst6:arm64 depends on x11-common; however:
  Package x11-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxtst6:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxvmc1:arm64:
 libxvmc1:arm64 depends on x11-common; however:
  Package x11-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxvmc1:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libice-dev:arm64:
 libice-dev:arm64 depends on libice6 (= 2:1.0.9-1+b1); however:
  Package libice6:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libice-dev:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsm-dev:arm64:
 libsm-dev:arm64 depends on libsm6 (= 2:1.2.2-1+b1); however:
  Package libsm6:arm64 is not configured yet.
 libsm-dev:arm64 depends on libice-dev (>= 1:1.0.0-1); however:
  Package libice-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libsm-dev:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxt-dev:arm64:
 libxt-dev:arm64 depends on libxt6 (= 1:1.1.4-1+b1); however:
  Package libxt6:arm64 is not configured yet.
 libxt-dev:arm64 depends on libsm-dev; however:
  Package libsm-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxt-dev:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxmu-dev:arm64:
 libxmu-dev:arm64 depends on libxt-dev; however:
  Package libxt-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.
 libxmu-dev:arm64 depends on libxmu6 (= 2:1.1.2-1); however:
  Package libxmu6:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxmu-dev:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxaw7-dev:arm64:
 libxaw7-dev:arm64 depends on libxaw7 (= 2:1.0.12-2+b1); however:
  Package libxaw7:arm64 is not configured yet.
 libxaw7-dev:arm64 depends on libxmu-dev; however:
  Package libxmu-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxaw7-dev:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxss-dev:arm64:
 libxss-dev:arm64 depends on libxss1 (= 1:1.2.2-1); however:
  Package libxss1:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxss-dev:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxtst-dev:arm64:
 libxtst-dev:arm64 depends on libxtst6 (= 2:1.2.2-1+b1); however:
  Package libxtst6:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxtst-dev:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxvmc-dev:arm64:
 libxvmc-dev:arm64 depends on libxvmc1 (= 2:1.0.8-2+b1); however:
  Package libxvmc1:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxvmc-dev:arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xorg-dev:
 xorg-dev depends on libice-dev; however:
  Package libice-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.
 xorg-dev depends on libsm-dev; however:
  Package libsm-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.
 xorg-dev depends on libxaw7-dev; however:
  Package libxaw7-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.
 xorg-dev depends on libxmu-dev; however:
  Package libxmu-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.
 xorg-dev depends on libxss-dev; however:
  Package libxss-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.
 xorg-dev depends on libxt-dev; however:
  Package libxt-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.
 xorg-dev depends on libxtst-dev; however:
  Package libxtst-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.
 xorg-dev depends on libxvmc-dev; however:
  Package libxvmc-dev:arm64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xorg-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 x11-common
 libice6:arm64
 libsm6:arm64
 libxt6:arm64
 libxmu6:arm64
 libxaw7:arm64
 libxss1:arm64
 libxtst6:arm64
 libxvmc1:arm64
 libice-dev:arm64
 libsm-dev:arm64
 libxt-dev:arm64
 libxmu-dev:arm64
 libxaw7-dev:arm64
 libxss-dev:arm64
 libxtst-dev:arm64
 libxvmc-dev:arm64
 xorg-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@localhost:/#
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you have some unconfigured packages.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

configure them in this order:

1. xserver-xorg
2. xorg
3. kubuntu-desktop

eg

```
sudo dpkg --configure xserver-xorg
```

Comment: When I run  `dpkg --configure x11-common` . I get this error :: 
`root@localhost:/# dpkg --configure x11-common
Setting up x11-common (1:7.7+7) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/x11-common.postinst: 697: /var/lib/dpkg/info/x11-common.postinst: update-rc.d: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package x11-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126Errors were encountered while processing:
 x11-common
root@localhost:/#`

Comment: Question. The medium with you chroot have the same arch (arm64)?